How can I block all requests to Docker containers from eth0?
I'm running some Docker containers on a machine, and I want all of my Docker containers to be only accessible on localhost (so caddy can use them) and from the tailscale0 interface only, so other machines in my Tailnet can connect.
My more immediate concern for this was to block port 9100, as will be seen from the commands I tried.
How would I go about doing this? I've tried the following commands taken from various posts on the internet, all to no avail.
sudo iptables -I DOCKER -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 9100 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I DOCKER -i tailscale0 -p tcp --dport 9100 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -I DOCKER -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 9100 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -m conntrack --ctdir ORIGINAL -j DROP
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 ! -s 127.0.0.1 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I DOCKER 1 -p tcp --dport 9100 -j DROP
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER 1 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 9100 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -p tcp -m conntrack --ctorigdstport 9100 --ctdir ORIGINAL -j DROP
sudo iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i eth0 -j DROP

